# AngularJS routing and location

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Is there a straight forward way of using routing/location information to build a url.

I want to automate redirection on changes to model. 
I was thinking of creating a module which will allow you to specify objects to watch. Changes to these objects would trigger a redirection using $location, but I don't know if it's possible to get the route maps from routing.

Comment: "using routing/location to build a url"  What exactly do you mean by this statement ?

Comment: While you will get responses indicating usage of `ngRoute` and `uiRouter` (and both will work) keep in mind that the router for angular2 will be supported in angular 1.3 (https://github.com/angular/router) note: still in progress as of now

Comment: I mean get the mappings for a controller from routing so I can correctly create a url. Use case being - user can pick a date from a drop down, triggering a redirect to the same controller, with the selected value in the url.Similar functionality exists in many controllers, requiring manual coding to determine url.I want to create a service which can be told what to watch, and the part of the routing map it relates to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has an 'official' module that can do things like this called [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) - although many users prefer the use of [uiRouter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (including myself). The way to do this would be to either use `$scope.$watch` in a controller, or `ng-change` to trigger `$state.go` (for uiRouter) or `$location.url` (for ngRoute).

Here is a potential example in uiRouter:

```
<div ng-controller='FooCtrl as foo'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='foo.bar' ng-change='foo.update(foo.bar)'>
</div>
```

```
angular.controller('FooCtrl', function($state) {
  this.update = function (model) {
    // depending on some properties in the model..
    $state.go('mystate', { model: model });
  };
})
```